# How does flutter realize the effect in the picture

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w997T.png)

How does flutter realize the effect of the middle icon

I tried the way of stack components, but it is not elegant enough. Is there an elegant way to achieve it? Implementation of z-index similar to css

Comment: 1. if u wanna show ur button gets clicked effed then use InkWell widget. 2. if u wanna have backgeoud shadow behind ur MiddleIcon then use Containes shadow

Comment: Sorry, my expression may not be accurate, I want to know how to achieve the stacking of the middle icon between the upper and lower components

Comment: U can use Stack & positioned it

Comment: The stack component needs to calculate the position of all subcomponents, which feels cumbersome to implement

Comment: not that complex u know. there r lot of ways to achieve that so it depends on ur choice, did u write any code if soo then share that. We may help u